# Angular 4 : ngNativeValidate is not allowed in Form

Tags: html, angular, forms

I'm using Angular 4 to build a form and **required** attribute is not working. I tried adding `<form ngNativeValidate>...</form>` as suggested by many answers but i got :

> Attribute ngNativeValidate is not allowed here.

Here is my code :

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" ngNativeValidate>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

      <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)] = "email" name='email' placeholder="Email"  required/>
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-def btn-block">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to replace this : `<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)] = "email" name='email' placeholder="Email"  required/>`

with this : `<input class="form-control" type="text" ngModel #email="ngModel" name='email' placeholder="Email"  required/>`

so all your code should look like this :

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

  <input class="form-control" type="text" ngModel #email="ngModel" name='email' placeholder="Email"  required/>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="!email.valid  && email.touched" >
    <span *ngIf="!email.valid"> This field is required</span>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-def btn-block">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Also remove the unnecessary ngNativeValidate and it should work now.

Comment: If my solution worked for you please mark it as an answer thank you.